# Is there a function in Python3 to copy the 3 smallest values in a row into a data frame, for m rows?

Tags: python-3.x, min, heapq

I'm trying to find the three smallest values for each row of a dataframe, and put them in a separate dataframe. I don't need to know which column they came from, but I do need to cycle through m rows where m might change for each dataframe I use.

I wanted to use heaps.nsmallest, but I'm not sure how to loop through each row and add the results to a new line of a dataframe each time. I seem to just get a single line of results as output.

```
 for x in range(len(df1)):
        heap=pd.DataFrame(heapq.nsmallest(3, df1[x]))
```

I expected this to loop through values of x, but it only produces one column with len(df1) rows. I think it's overwriting the previous results, as it always gives the three minimum values from the last row.

Comment: You override the variable heap each time

Comment: Is there a add method for the dataFrame?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've tried creating heap[x] and it works!

Comment: For some reason, I've reopened the notebook, and now it says "Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([heapq.nsmallest(3, df1[x])
                   for x in range(len(df1))])
```

or, use `sorted(df1[x])[:3]`